# How to display the content of a text file into jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a web project. After executing the project it will generate a text file that will contain certain result. And in the final jsp page just contains success report. But I want to show the content of the text file in to that jsp page. What i need to do to achive this?

Thanks.
koushik

Answer (score 6):

If the file is saved in public webcontent, then use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:import>` to display it.

```xml
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<pre><c:import url="file.txt" /></pre>
```

*The `<pre>` tag is necessary so that newlines are been preserved in HTML output. Alternatives are adding CSS `white-space: pre;` to the containing element, or replacing `\n` with `<br/>`.*

If the file is not saved in public webcontent, then create a servlet which gets an `InputStream` of it by `FileInputStream` and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse` so that you can finally use `<c:import>` for this.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 1:
you need to open the txt file, read content & write it to the outputstream.

```
BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("<<file>>"));

String line = br.readLine();
while(line!=null){
 out.println(line);
 line = br.readLine();
}
```

this reads the file & write the contents to the jsp

this needs to be done in the JSP...

its also advisable to move this piece of code to a support class & use that class to retrieve the file contents.

Comment: Yes, you may want to add <br>s at the end of each line if this is an html jsp.

Comment: that one will build :

        BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader( new java.io.FileReader( filename ) );
        String line = null;
        while ( null != ( line = reader.readLine() )) { out.write(line);   
}
        reader.close();

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from InputStreamReader to BufferedReader

Answer (score 0):

Is the text file generated by your web application as a result of a user request? If so, then your action bean (or servlet) which triggered the generation of the file must have access to its content. Couldn't you set the file content as an action bean property (or servlet parameter), in which case the JSP would have access to it and can then display it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL *import* tag. It imports the content of a URL-based resource.

```
<c:import var="data" 
          url="http://www.example.com/file.txt"
          scope="session"/>

<c:out value="${data}"/>
```